# Проверка строки на допустимые символы \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Сделала вот такую функцию. Суть которой проверка символов в строке, если указанный диапазон 'A'..'Z' + 'a'..'z' + '0'..'9' есть, в строке, то функция возвращает True.

**Вопрос!:** **Меня смущает скорость**, кто что посоветует - для её оптимизации. Ну хотя бы взять то что: **у меня 4 - цикла "for"** и это дает о себе знать (низкая скорость). Плюс проверка комбинаций (обязательных условий), то есть в строке должны быть символы:

```
'A'..'Z' + 'a'..'z' + '0'..'9'
'0'..'9'+ 'A'..'Z' + 'a'..'z'
'a'..'z' 'A'..'Z' + '0'..'9'
```

Может кто **подскажет или опубликует свой вариант**. Благодарна заранее за подсказки...

**Вот сама - функция (полностью рабочая но медленная до ужаса):**

```
function IsGood(AInpStr: String; AMinLen, AMaxLen: Integer;
  AAlowOnlyLetters: Boolean = True): Boolean;
var
  i, j, m: Integer;
  a, b, c, d, k: Boolean;
  a1, b1, c1, d1, k1: Boolean;
  Len: Integer;
  CU, CL, SF: TSysCharSet;
begin

  Result := False;
  Len := Length(AInpStr);

  CU := ['A' .. 'Z'];
  CL := ['a' .. 'z'];
  SF := ['0' .. '9'];

  // Флаг разрешающий только буквы или вообще любые символы, по умолчанию - включено
  // True   - Разрешить только указанный диапазон для поиска
  // False  - Разрешить включение и других символов для поиска
  if AAlowOnlyLetters then
  begin
    for i := 1 to Len do
    begin
      a := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], CU);
      b := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], CL);
      k1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], SF);
      if not(a or b or k1) then
        Exit;
    end;
  end;

  // разрешаем минимальную и максимальную длину
  if not((Len >= AMinLen) and (Len <= AMaxLen)) then
    Exit;

  for i := 1 to Len do
  begin
    k1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], SF);
    a := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], CU);
    b := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], CL);

    for j := i to Len do
    begin
      c := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CU);
      d := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CL);
      a1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CU);
      b1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CL);

      for m := i to Len do
      begin
        k := CharInSet(AInpStr[m], SF);
        c1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[m], CU);
        d1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[m], CL);

        // Вот тут идет проверка разных комбинаций
        if (a and d and k) or (b and c and k) or (k1 and a1 and d1) or
          (k1 and b1 and c1)
        // Ну и тут вывод результата если строка подходит под условия
        then
        begin
          Result := True;
          Exit;
        end
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что здесь происходит? Зачем одно и то же делается по два раза?

```
  c := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CU);
  d := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CL);
  a1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CU);
  b1 := CharInSet(AInpStr[j], CL);
```

> если указанный диапазон 'A'..'Z' + 'a'..'z' + '0'..'9' есть, в строке

что значит эта фраза?

---

```
  colonIndex = Pos(":", AInpStr);
  if colonIndex = 0 then
    exit;

  hasLower := false;
  hasUpper := false;
  hasDigit := false;

  for i := colonIndex + 1 to Len do
  begin
    c := AInpStr[i];
    hasLower := hasLower or CharInSet(c, CL);
    hasUpper := hasUpper or CharInSet(c, CU);
    hasDigit := hasDigit or CharInSet(c, SF);
    if hasLower and hasUpper and hasDigit then
    begin
      Result := true;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86040/discussion-on-answer-by-igor------delphixe).

Comment: Игорь, А еще такой вопрос: Если попадаются спец-символы в строке то функция их тоже учитывает. А по идее результат должен состоять с - Больших букв + маленьких букв + чисел, исключая спец-символы. Как правильно прописать это в вашем коде?

Comment: @Татьяна Я не понимаю, что значит "учитывает". Лучше задайте новый вопрос, где объясните, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function IsGood(const str : string; minLen,maxLen : integer; canUpper, canLower, canDigit : boolean) : boolean;
    var
     bytes : TBytes;
     cnt : integer;
    begin
    Result:=false;
    cnt:=Length(str);
    if (cnt<minLen) or (cnt>maxLen) then
      Exit;
    bytes:=BytesOf(str);
    for cnt:=0 to High(bytes) do
      begin
      if (canUpper and (bytes[cnt]>=$41) and (bytes[cnt]<=$5A))// -- A..Z
        or (canLower and (bytes[cnt]>=$61) and (bytes[cnt]<=$7A))// -- a..z
        or (canDigit and(bytes[cnt]>=$30) and (bytes[cnt]<=$39))// -- 0..9
        then Continue;
      Exit;
      end;
    Result:=true;
    end;
```